# unknown type name, expected identifier in c

Tags: c

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int menunum;
    int operand1, operand2;
    printf("Select number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", operand1);
    printf("Select number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", operand2);
    
    printf("Select operation: \n");
    printf("(1) add(+)\t(2) sub(-)\n");
    scanf("%d", &menunum);
    
    switch (menunum) {
      case 1:
        printf("Result: %d+%d=%d", operand1, operand2, operand1 + operand2);
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("Result: %d-%d=%d", operand1, operand2, operand1 - operand2);
        break;
    }
```

When I run the compiler, I get this error:

```
test.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 's'
s
^
test.c:1:2: error: expected identifier or '('
s
 ^
2 errors generated.
```

please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close as simple typo/not reproducible. Partially because of the extremely common FAQ about missing & in scanf, partially because there is no pre-processor token `s` in this code so I doubt this is the actual code giving that compiler error. Post a [mcve].

Comment: The error is puzzling: it looks like the file **test.c** contains a single byte `s`. Check your working environment and make sure the source file is in the same directory as the one you are compiling from.

Comment: Thank you so much! I modified the code and changed the compiler path, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Check first and second scanf of your code you have missed Ampersand (&) before operand1 and operand2 and also add a close curly bracket for your main function.

```
scanf("%d", &operand1);
scanf("%d", &operand2);
```

**Note**
The ampersand (&) allows us to pass the address of variable number which is the place in memory where we store the information that scanf read.

> Updated Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int menunum;
    int operand1, operand2;
    printf("Select number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &operand1);
    printf("Select number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &operand2);

    printf("Select operation: \n");
    printf("(1) add(+)\t(2) sub(-)\n");
    scanf("%d", &menunum);

    switch(menunum) {
        case 1:
            printf("Result: %d+%d=%d", operand1, operand2, operand1+operand2);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Result: %d-%d=%d", operand1, operand2, operand1 - operand2);
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I add  Ampersand (&) before operand1 and operand2, but error is still :(

Comment: But it works for me. Did you add close curly bracket? Because in your code main function closing curly bracket is missing.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!  I modified the code and changed the compiler path, the error was resolved.